# CSS transition on vertical-align property

Tags: css

How can I make a div that has vertical align:top, change it's position to vertical-align: middle, but have a smooth animated transition through those states?

I can't get it to work, is vertical-align non transitionable?

Code:

```
.outer{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
}

.inner{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  display:table-cell;
  transition:all 2s;
}

.inner:hover{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7amp783t/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the `vertical-align` property, use `transform: translateY()` to move up and down.

I've had a fiddle and got this code to work:

```
.outer{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
}

.inner{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.inner:hover{
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The `translateY(-50%)` moves the text "up" (hence the `-`) by 50% of the height of its parent box.

**EDIT** You don't need to worry about setting the `position: relative` of the parent div. I've removed it for clarity.

I've updated [your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7amp783t/2/), also.

Comment: you can drop sizing inner since it is a cell, it is 200px high anyway ;) everybody did it :)

Comment: Certainly can; I only pasted this from the original JSFiddle code and didn't think to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I had been struggling due to the need for using percentages rather than set amounts due to the site being responsive

Answer (score 2):

**if you want to use vertical-align**, you should not use inside a table-cell but with 2 elements side by side, where you can set values around the line-height they produce. In this case, vertical-align can take lots predefined values or numerics values.

> https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align#Values

Because your example gives an height of 200px, we may play around this : https://jsfiddle.net/7amp783t/5/

```css
.outer{
  font-size:18px;/* whatever */
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
}
.outer:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;/* here the line is 100% height of container: set to 200px */
  vertical-align:calc(-200px + 1em); /*chrome instead bottom */
}
.inner{
  vertical-align:0;/* from bottom : calc(-200px + 2em) go all the way down minus room for text */;
  display:inline-block;
  transition:all 2s;
}

.outer:hover .inner{/* outer, else you need to follow inner */
  vertical-align:calc(-100px + 1em);/* lets go half way */
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Hover me box 
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This solution is too verbose and complicated for such a simple issue. Plus you are using arbitrary "magic" numbers unnecessarily relying on exact pixel values. With a responsive stance, this would be a pain in the rear to maintain/override everywhere else in CSS. See my example above.

Comment: @GeoffJames this is meant to help the  op to understand how vertical-align works, and that the first idea op had might not be pertinent as he thought. from the 200px of op example, it **can** work ...  the idea is not bad at first but needs a second thought (from my screen, your answer is the third below ;) )

Comment: Whilst I don't disagree that it can work, I think it might have been going beyond the context of what the poster's desired outcome was. That's just my opinion, though; and your post is certainly informative.

Comment: keyword is in question title, there is obviously a misknowledge about it. answers do not always need to be the solution , but also can tell why or how it works ;) , relative + top:50% works too and even IE6 will understand it ... good to know how things works .. it  gives reason to choose

Answer (score 1):

[CSS Transitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css) defines `vertical-align` as animatable, but only when interpolating between two length values.

```
┌────────────────┬───────────┐
│ Property Name  │ Type      │
├────────────────┼───────────┤
│ vertical-align │ as length │
└────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Therefore, transitions between `bottom` and `middle` won't be smooth.

If you were using `vertical-align` to align an inline-level element relatively to its line box, you could try using length values.

However, you are using it on a table cell, which has a different behavior, as defined in [Table height algorithms](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout). In particular, length values don't apply to table cells.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Jquery to create a sliding animation. You can use jQuery's toogle function to do so.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: No, you don't have to use jQuery to create a sliding animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try **transform** instead of vertical aligning it to middle. This code will do same what you are trying to accomplish. Change your hover state to include  **translateY(-50%)**

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7amp783t/3/)

```
.outer{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
}

.inner{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  display:table-cell;
   transition:all 2s;
}

.inner:hover{
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this sample:

using the transform: translateY(-50%); method
[css vertical align animation](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3wL5jeex/2/)

```
 .block {
 background: orange;
 height: 500px;


}
 .centered {
     text-align: center;
     background: pink;
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     -webkit-transition: all .5s;
     -moz-transition: all .5s;
     -o-transition: all .5s;
     transition: all .5s;
 }
 .block:hover .centered {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     top: 50%;
 }
```

let me know if u need further help

Answer (score 0):

position:relative can be an easy way:

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.inner:hover {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Hover me
  </div>
</div>
```